# Converting a UML Diagram into Code

Tags: java, uml

I am having issues converting this UML Diagram setup into code. I understand the Class is the top portion followed by the variables and the methods. I am very new to Java and this is probably the most confusing thing I've ever encountered. I'm not 100% sure how to create the "model" or the main code section for this but this is the code I have started/attempted for the Domain class so far. Am I on the right track? Or am I just completely lost. Any tips, or something to send me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
  //This is the main .java file
  public class Assignment3 extends Application {



@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 300); // Set canvas Size in Pixels
    stage.setTitle("FXGraphicsTemplate"); // Set window title
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    Castle stateDomain = new Castle();
    Castle drawDomain = new Castle();

    stage.show();
    }
 

 public static void main (String[] args) {
     launch ( args );
 }

 // .class file that is utterly awful and I don't know where to go
 
 public class Castle {


 private String castleName;
 private double castleSize;
 private double castleX;
 private double castleY;
 private int domainX;
 private int domainY;
 private String castleColor;
 private String domainName;



public void stateDomain ( String castleName, int domainX, int domainY, String castleColor ) {
    this.castleName = castleName;
    this.domainX = domainX;
    this.domainY = domainY;
    this.castleColor = castleColor;    
}

public void drawDomain ( GraphicsContext gc ) {
    
    
    
}
```

I want to point out I am just looking for some direction. Anything at this point would be incredibly helpful, whether it's a link to another post or a sliver of code that gets my brain going.
Thank you.

Comment: The diagram is incomplete: `Gate` and `ArrowSlit` are no named. Neither as local attribute nor via a role name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most abstract way to describe static relationship between classes is using the Association link, which simply states that there is some kind of a link or a dependency between two classes or more. There is the weak and the Strong Association.
For your case i will consider it to be the strong association.

```
public class Domain 
{
    private double x, y, size;
    private String name;

    public void state(String name, int x, int y, Color color) {
            //TODO
    }

    public void draw(arguments) {
        //TODO
    }
}


public class Castle
    {
        //all arguments in diagram and now you need a reference to the class Domain

        private Domain domain;

        //The rest is just writing what is in the diagram

    }
```

but i must say your diagram is very incomplete. Please take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

Comment: I can work with this, a push forward to get my brain going. I appreciate the input!!

Comment: Also, not my diagram. It's an assignment for school which is why I don't want somebody to write out an answer for me. I want to learn and apply myself to get it done. But being confused about where to start can get frustrating.

Comment: If that's an assignment you should be careful with what that teacher is telling you :-/ The two castles have 2 arrow slits each, but the number of doors is indefinite (could be 0 to infinity).